# strip the microseconds from the data and convert to string format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying the strip the microseconds from the list and trying to convert it to character. But i get error. Please help me in achieving the result.

**list data:**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
ab = pd.date_range(start='2018-04-24', end='2018-04-27', periods=50)
ab = ab[:5].tolist()
ab

[Timestamp('2018-04-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-04-24 01:28:09.795918367'),
 Timestamp('2018-04-24 02:56:19.591836734'),
 Timestamp('2018-04-24 04:24:29.387755102'),
 Timestamp('2018-04-24 05:52:39.183673469')]
```

**code i tried:**

```
def ts1(times):
    return times.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

list(map(times, ab))
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

**Expected Result**

```
['2018-04-24 00:00:00',
 '2018-04-24 01:28:09',
 '2018-04-24 02:56:19',
 '2018-04-24 04:24:29',
 '2018-04-24 05:52:39']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is correct, if you do `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` on your pandas dataframe `Datetime` object as show below,

```
ab = ab[:5].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").tolist()
ab
```

or

modify `list(map(times, ab))` to `list(map(ts1, ab))`

**Output:**

```
['2018-04-24 00:00:00',
 '2018-04-24 01:28:09',
 '2018-04-24 02:56:19',
 '2018-04-24 04:24:29',
 '2018-04-24 05:52:39']
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is due to a small typo. In your code, you're trying to call a function named times, but you actually named your function ts1.

```
result = list(map(ts1, ab))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a list of strings and cut off everything you don't want.

```
Templist = []    
for elem in ab:
    Temp = str(elem)
    Templist.append(Temp[:19])
ab = Templist
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer. Also, Templist is not defined here.